# Why doesn't ssh-keygen let me type in my passphrase in the prompt?

Tags: ssh

Note: this is not real information:

```
$ ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "tekkub@gmail.com"
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/c/Users/Tekkub/.ssh/id_rsa):

ssh.txt
```

I entered a file name here. Not sure if I should have:

```
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase):
```

I am stuck here. I type and it doesn't work.

Comment: Just in case: passwords normally don't show up in the console when you type them. That is intended. Have you tried and entered a password?

Comment: you should just press return and enter no passphrase, creating public keys is so you can NOT have to enter passwords in ssh, setting a passphrase will still require that passphrase at every login even with the public key installed, which defeats the purpose of creating a public key to use with git so it doesn't ask for your password.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Passwords normally don't show up in the console when you type them. That is intended. Just type your password, hit enter and repeat. It will work.

Answer (score 2):

That's why ssh comes with a program called ssh-agent which caches your passphrase (Okay, it actually caches the decrypted key, not the passphrase, same result). That way you can have a passphrase on your key and still not have to type it each time.